# How to efficiently skip to a particular line in a file?

Tags: php, performance, file, io

I know I can read a file line-by-line with [this function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), and then I could just do something like `if($line_no < $X) continue;`, but I was wondering if there was anything more efficient? These could be some potentially large files I'm reading and I don't want to stuff everything into a gigantic array, most of which I'm going to ignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP can't jump to a specific line using line numbers only without additional processing.  If you have the number of *bytes* to skip, you can simply use `fseek()`.

If running out of memory simply using `file()` is a concern, I can't help you, but you can use:

```
$file = array_slice(file(__FILE__), __LINE__ - 1));
```

To get the lines after the desired line without adding anything unnecessary to memory.  This should be relatively fast even on large files.

If that's still not enough, you might want to consider using a different language.

Comment: I'll try it that way... it probably *won't* be an issue, but it seems pretty wasteful. All it would have to do is read the file in chunks and count the number of `\n`'s, rather than reading in the whole file at once.

Comment: @Mark I did a benchmark of using `fgets()` to read lines vs. using `file()`.  In terms of speed and memory usage they are actually about equal, so I don't know that you will get much benefit from complicating your code past the one line I have presented you.